# Probability of takeover announcement in the next hour

Tags: probability

I have encountered a problem:

> The probability that at least one company is going to announce a takeover in the next hour is 84%. What is the probability that at least one announces in the next 30 minutes, assuming that the distribution of announcement times is uniformly distributed?

Their solution to the problem is:

> Correct answer: 60%
>
> If the desired probability is $p$  then the probability of no announcement in a half hour is $1 - p$  so the probability of no announcement in the next hour is $(1-p)^2 = 1-0.84$

I believe that the solution is wrong because the probabilities of non announcements in consecutive half-hours are not independent so it is not possible to use the formula $(1-p)^2 = 1-0.84$.

I believe that the probability is 42 % because the CDF of uniform distribution is linear. Am I correct?

Comment: The given problem is so poorly worded, it is no wonder that their answer is also obviously flawed, as you correctly point out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the distribution of announcement times may be uniform, the distribution of the number of announcements per hour is Poisson with mean $\lambda$ given by $$p(X\geq1)=1-p(X=0)=1-e^{-\lambda}=0.84$$
$$\implies\lambda=-\ln0.16$$

Therefore the probability of at least one announcement in a half hour period is $$1-e^{-\frac 12\lambda}=1-e^{\ln0.4}=0.6$$

Comment: Interesting... but is their approach correct? In degenerate case, if the probability of an announcement in an hour was 100 %, then their formula would output the probability of announcement in half hour also 100 % which is wrong isn't it?

Comment: I have just checked and your formula $p = 1 - e^{\frac{1}{2}\ln(1-x)}$ seems to be equivalent with theirs $p = 1 -\sqrt{1-x}$ (where x is 0.84), so indeed it looks like their approach is correct.